# Why MYSQL Desc command showing char instead of nchar?

Tags: mysql, nvarchar

I have created two columns in a tables with NATIONAL VARCHAR Data Type? But, when i am running the command, 
desc 
The result shows the datatype as varchar, not nvarchar. Why is it so? Am i doing some thing wrong?

```
PENAME NATIONAL VARCHAR(255),
PNAME NATIONAL VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
```

Comment: As per the docs, NATIONAL VARCHAR or NVARCHAR is a shorthand for MySQL's VARCHAR.

Comment: Not sure whether they exist in mySQL at all? They are accepted when *creating* a table, but internally I think it becomes a VARCHAR. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-national.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL does not have separation of nvarchar and varchar (like SQL Server).

Instead, you define the [CHARACTER SET (aka CHARSET)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-syntax.html) to describe the data (ansi, utf8 etc) therein. This is orthoganal to collation in MySQL ([collation defines how the data is sorted and compared](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/4272/630))

`NATIONAL VARCHAR (n)` is just a synonym for `VARCHAR (n) CHARACTER SET utf8`